# ElGamal with elliptic curves and semantic security

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption, semantic-security

To encrypt a group element $P$ with public key $K$ and randomness $r$ using ElGamal on elliptic curves with base point $G$ we do the following $(c_1, c_2) = (r\cdot G; P+r\cdot K)$.

When we want to encrypt a free-form message $m$, we have to convert it to a group element $P$ first. For that, we can either use scalar multiplication $P=m\cdot G$ (additively homomorphic) or map the message  $P = map(m)$ (multiplicative homomorphic). The former gives *not just a point*, but a group element. The latter is more complicated.

All methods I found map a message to a curve point ([Koblitz's approach](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76343/55097), [its variant](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76345/55097), [injective encoding article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/373.pdf)). However, there is no guarantee that the resulting point belongs to the cyclic group (i.e. has the right order).

So using **encoding to just EC point** results in **not semantically securing ElGamal**. It's basically similar to leaking if the message is a quadratic residue or not when using $G_q$ over finite fields with $p = 2q+1$ and messages from $Z_p^*$ without encoding (details about why the leakage happens are [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54919/55097) or [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59652/55097)).

Is there any way to encode a random message to the EC point of the correct order (i.e. group element)? Is there a way to convert EC point to a group element?

Comment: The encoding $P=m\cdot G$ has a drawback: it makes decryption computationally intractable.

Comment: [Elligator 1 and Elligator 2](https://elligator.cr.yp.to/)

Comment: @fgrieu, true. It works only for a very small message space, plus requires precomputing a table for decryption or many iterations to "recover" $m$ from $m\cdot G$ i.e. break dlog. But so far I don't see any other way to get semantically secure ElGamal while keeping its homomorphic properties.

Comment: @kelalaka, thank you! I'll take a closer look. From the first glance, it seems like an improvement of injective encoding by Fouque et. al. Thus I'm afraid, it's again encoding to a point of the curve and not to its large prime order subgroup (i.e. correct point order is not guaranteed).

Comment: @kelalaka, unfortunately, Elligator doesn’t always give points with the right order. Seems like an open problem in ECC